# Keras ASR model validation steps

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, speech-recognition, prediction

I am a newbie in Machine learning. I would like to design a model of ASR(Automatic speech recognition), so I came across the following link is:

https://keras.io/examples/audio/transformer_asr/

I am able to understand the training model concept. I also saved the above model using the following code:

```
model.save_weights('data_sa',save_format='hdf5')
```

then I load it again using:

```
model.load_weights('/content/data_sa')
```

Now, I would like to predict the model, by giving the validation data set. But I am facing an issue.

I am using the following step for prediction:

```
model.predict(np.array(val_ds)) #this is the validation dataset
```

It is giving an error of tensor conversion.

I tried to search the possible solution to this step but couldn't able to find the it.

Answer (score 0):

tf.cast() and tf.to_float() are TensorFlow functions, so you'd get them using import tensorflow as tf.

Comment: So, in this way my code will look like this: `model.predict(np.array(tf.cast(val_ds)))` ?

Comment: model.predict(val_ds , dtype = tf.float32)

Comment: other wise check this. 

model.predict(tf.convert_to_tensor([val_ds]))